# Svelte not including computed properties in bundle. No errors are produced

Tags: javascript, computed-properties, svelte

I am using [Svelte computed properties example](https://svelte.technology/guide#computed-properties). Specifically I am copying the example:

In Works.html

```
<h1>{hours}</h1>
```

And in my JS

```
const workViewer = new WorkViewer({
    target: document.querySelector('.works-wrapper'),
    data: function(){
        return {
            time: new Date()
        }
    },
    computed: {
        hours: ({ time }) => time.getHours()
    }
});
```

Rollup compiles my Svelte bundle without errors:

```
rollup v0.58.2
bundles public/js/index.js → public\js\bundle.js...
created public\js\bundle.js in 668ms

[2018-07-18 13:39:37] waiting for changes...
```

However in browser the resulting module is missing all the computer properies. `hours` for example is exactly as mentioned in

```
<Works> was created without expected data property 'hours' bundle.js:12488:34
```

**Why was the computed property not included in the bundle?**

How can I make it be included in the bundle?

Comment: Is that the complete component source code? `data` should be a function that *returns* an object, not an object itself — the code above should [cause a compile error](https://svelte.technology/repl?version=2.9.5&gist=b013ed0017f03571c82d5752e9cf3e0a)

Comment: @RichHarris making data an object doesn't return a compile error. I've adjusted `data` to be a function, and  edited the code above (which still causes the same error)

Answer (score 3):

Computed properties must be part of the component definition, not the instantiation options — i.e. like this:

```html
{hours}

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return { time: new Date() }
    },
    computed: {
      hours: ({ time }) => time.getHours()
    }
  };
</script>
```

Svelte determines which computed properties depend on which other properties, and generates code (after sorting them topologically, in the case where one computed property depends on another) that does the minimum work possible to recompute values. That's only possible at compile time, which is why it has to be part of the input to the compiler rather than a runtime option.

I didn't realise earlier that these were initialisation options — in that case data *is* an object, rather than a function for generating default data. It's like Ractive in that respect.

Comment: Can I define my component in JS (ie, outside where the HTML lives), like I did in `new Ractive()` when using Ractive? Or do both the template and the JS have to live in the .html file? I /swear/ I saw examples of importing the HTML and creating a component with it.

Comment: Wait now I'm super confused: The example at https://svelte.technology/guide#understanding-svelte-components shows `data` as part of instantiation options - why isn't `computed` OK?

Comment: No, components must always be defined in an .html file, SFC-style. The whole point of Svelte is that it's doing a lot of work at compile time so that it doesn't have to do it at run time — for that, it needs components to be authored in a predictable form. It's not compiling arbitrary JavaScript